# WCF 4.0 ConcurrencyMode.Multiple and InstanceContextMode.Single Scalabiltity

Tags: wcf, scalability

I have a stateless WCF 4.0 (IIS 7.5) configured with

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]

Question 1
Does InstanceContextMode.Single have any impact when configuring ConcurrencyMode.Multiple ?

Question 1
In order to have better Scalabiltity (hunders calls per second), should I change it to InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall ?

Thanks